# PHP isset not working on form submit after confirmation using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a form with **multiple submit button** like following:

```
<form action="insert_data" method="post" id="topSubmit">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stories[]" id="stories" value="A">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stories[]" id="stories" value="B">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stories[]" id="stories" value="C">
    <!--   more checkboxes    -->
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="trunc-trend" id="trunc-trend" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-trunc-trend">
        Add Stories 1
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="trunc-top" id="trunc-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-trunc-top">
        Add Stories 2 
    </button>
</form>
```

For each submit button there is a **confirmation modal(bootstrap)** like following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-trunc-trend" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4 style="text-align: center;">Are you sure to do this action ?</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
                    <button type="button" name="ensure-trunc-trend" id="ensure-trunc-trend" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 15px">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The following is my jQuery code, where, i at first prevent page loading on submit button click so that it does not submit from before confirmation, like following:

```
$('#trunc-trend').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then, after clicking on the **Yes** Button in bootstrap modal that is : `<button type="button" name="ensure-trunc-trend" id="ensure-trunc-trend" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 15px">Yes</button>`

the following jQuery execute:

```
$('#ensure-trunc-trend').click(function(){
    $('#topSubmit').submit();
});
```

This takes me to the next php page. There are some isset condition in this php page for each submit button in the form. But these isset condition is not working.

This is my php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['trunc-trend'])) {
    echo "coming here.";
}

elseif (isset($_POST['trunc-top'])) {
    echo "this is working";
}
```

Any idea how this isset condition may work ?

Comment: Make sure that your post variables actually contain any data. Your syntax for the conditions is correct, so my suspicion is that your post variables are empty.

Comment: check what are you getting in POST, are you even getting these

Comment: _“There are some isset condition in this php page for each submit button in the form. But these isset condition is not working.”_ - yes, they _are_ working - they evaluate to false, because the values you are checking for do not exist. You did not submit the form by clicking one of the submit buttons (you explicitly prevented that from happening, and are submitting the form by calling the submit method afterwards), so there is no entry in the POST data for any of them either.

Comment: trunc-trend and trunc-top are buttons with no value according to your code so the are "not set" when evaluated by php. Probably you wanted a hidden input field in your form that changes value when one of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: @AhmedSunny i tried with both sending some post values and without sending anything.

Comment: @misorude any idea what should i do here so that isset condition evaluates true ? can you give me a sample code snippet ?

Comment: You could for example have the JS part write the action to perform (according to which submit button was clicked) into a hidden form field, so that you can take the value from there to decide which action your PHP script has to perform.

Comment: try !empty() instead of isset

Comment: @AhmedSunny still not working using !empty()

Comment: o i think, its not sent in post because its a button, not input type submit. make it input with type submit. will work then

Comment: @AhmedSunny tried with input type submit. Still not working.

Comment: what is really happend add some flow and post. 
close modal before  $('#topSubmit').submit();

Answer (score -1):

The variables `$_POST['trunc-trend']` and `$_POST['trunc-trop']` come from two different submit buttons, but you are submitting the form porgramatically ( `$('#topSubmit').submit();` ). The submit inputs are only sent when they are clicked, so your PHP script doesn't receives them.

If you try this:

```
$('#ensure-trunc-trend').click(function(){
        $('button[name=trunc-trend]').click();
});
```

you'll get the `truc-trend`variable.